# Can't compile exist C++ source code in Android Studio

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk

I want to use [this library](https://github.com/taku910/mecab) in android so, I follow [this guide](http://www.sureshjoshi.com/mobile/android-ndk-in-android-studio-with-swig/) and I think what I should do in order to use it is

1. Compile source code in Android Studio by NDK
2. Use Swig to generate Java wrapper class

So, I installed NDK and follow [this guide](http://www.shaneenishry.com/blog/2014/08/17/ndk-with-android-studio/) and [this](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental) to setting up Android Studio to compile [source code](https://github.com/taku910/mecab/tree/master/mecab/src).

This is setting in `android.ndk` section from module's `build.gradle`

```
android.ndk {
    moduleName = "MeCab"
    stl = "stlport_shared"
}
```

When I after I compile(Make Project), lot of errors was reported, almost of all of it is `error: 'xxx' has not been declared` and some `error: ... has incomplete type`

I think this because `#ifdef HAVE_*` doesn't work at all so, I tried to remove `#ifdef HAVE_*` and include head file directly then compile to see result if errors are fixed.

The result it that I directly include `<sys/stat.h>`, `<fcntl.h>` in [mmap.h](https://github.com/taku910/mecab/blob/master/mecab/src/mmap.h), `<stdint.h>` in [utils.h](https://github.com/taku910/mecab/blob/master/mecab/src/utils.h), `<dirent.h>` in [utils.cpp](https://github.com/taku910/mecab/blob/master/mecab/src/utils.cpp) and `<cctype>` in [param.cpp](https://github.com/taku910/mecab/blob/master/mecab/src/param.cpp)(I may forgot some) and every `error: 'xxx' has not been declared` and `error: ... has incomplete type` are not shown again.
**First question: Did I use the right solution to fix it?**

Other errors that was reported with above errors is
In [dictionary.cpp](https://github.com/taku910/mecab/blob/master/mecab/src/dictionary.cpp) `error: 'DIC_VERSION' was not declared in this scope`
In [param.cpp](https://github.com/taku910/mecab/blob/master/mecab/src/tagger.cpp) `error: 'PACKAGE' was not declared in this scope` and `error: 'VERSION' was not declared in this scope`
In [tagger.cpp](https://github.com/taku910/mecab/blob/master/mecab/src/tagger.cpp) `error: 'VERSION' was not declared in this scope`
And in [utils.cpp](https://github.com/taku910/mecab/blob/master/mecab/src/utils.cpp) `error: 'MECAB_DEFAULT_RC' was not declared in this scope`

I found those variables in [Makefile.in](https://github.com/taku910/mecab/blob/master/mecab/src/Makefile.in) and those variables with values in  [configure](https://github.com/taku910/mecab/blob/master/mecab/configure) but I don't know how these file relate to variables in source code.
**Second question: How can I fix these errors?**

Last error isn't reported in Messages Gradle Build but is underlined with red line in [mmap.h](https://github.com/taku910/mecab/blob/master/mecab/src/mmap.h)

```
...

const T* begin()    const  { return text; }
T*       end()           { return text + size(); }
const T* end()    const  { return text + size(); }
size_t size()               { return length/sizeof(T); }

...
```

At `size()` in `const T* end()    const  { return text + size(); }` said `Non-const function 'size()' is called from const function`, I think this is seem like we can't refer to instance field from static context in C# but in this case **How should I fix it?**I think this isn't author mistake.**

I don't know is this a helpful information, it is [How to install(Japanese)](http://taku910.github.io/mecab/#install)

> Requirement
>      - C++ compiler (g++ 3.4.3 or VC7)
>      - iconv(libiconv): use to convert dictionary
>      installation
>      it can be installed in the same procedure as the general free software
>      % tar zxfv mecab-X.X.tar.gz
>
> ```
> % cd mecab-X.X
> % ./configure 
> % make
> % make check
> % su
> # make install
> ```
>
> Dictionary install
>
> ```
> % tar zxfv mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-XXXX.tar.gz
> % mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-XXXX
> % ./configure
> % make
> % su
> # make install
> ```

How to compile from [official document(Japanese at the end of file)](https://github.com/taku910/mecab/blob/master/mecab/doc/libmecab.html)

> Unix
>
> ```
> % cc -O2 `mecab-config --cflags` example.c -o example \
>      `mecab-config --libs`
> ```
>
> Windows
>      in order to compile copy include\mecab.h, bin\libmecab.dll >lib\libmecab.lib
>      cygwin/mingw environment
>
> ```
> % gcc -DDLL_IMPORT -I. example.c -o example.exe libmecab.dll
> ```
>
> VC++ environment
>
> ```
> % cl -DDLL_IMPORT -I. example.c libmecab.lib
> ```

I'm using Windows 10, Android Studio 1.4, NDK r10e

Comment: Definitely, **`Mmap::size()`** should be declared **`const`**. If this is not marked by other compilers, it's their problem, not NDK's.

Comment: @AlexCohn I declared `Mmap::size()` as `const`, now underline error is gone.  But I still don't understand if `Mmap::size()` should be const, how author and other people can compile it(not in Android Studio), though I haven't tried to compile it outside Android Studio.

Comment: Some compilers may be less strict, or clever enough to understand that size() does not change the object, or they can accept a flag to ignore this sort of errors